# Bash enter & ctrl-z keypress

Tags: linux, bash, unix, openwrt

I have a command for minicom, send a SMS via modem with SSH/Putty , here is the command

```
AT^HCMGS="destination number"<press ENTER>
> SMS message <press CTRL + Z>
```

Command is successfully executed with minicom

I want to ask how to simulate press ENTER & CTRL+Z in bash
Can I write script like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e -n "AT^HCMGS="888"(I don't know how to insert enter/return)" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo -e -n "SMS message (I don't know how to insert ctrl+z)" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I want to integrate a program (motion linux) with this script in openWRT

Thank you!

Comment: Try `\032` for `^Z` part & `\n` for `ENTER`.

Comment: Plus, you'd need to escape `"` around `888`. Use `\"888\"`.

Comment: Assuming that CTRL+Z is actually suspending the program, the "right way" to do that would be `kill -STOP $PID`.  You can pipe echo (without `-n`) or otherwise send `\n` to get the enter key.

Comment: Another option that often works is Ctrl+v => Key you want to have.

E.g. `Ctrl+v`  then press `<Return key>`

Answer (score 3):

To send a message *test* to number *+48333444555* from shell:

```
echo -e 'AT+CMGS="+48333444555"^Mtest^Z' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Important**:

1. to get ^M You need press Ctrl+V and then Ctrl+M
2. to get ^Z You need press Ctrl+V and then Ctrl+Z

Comment: The question asks how to write this into a bash script. This answer is specifically dependent on executing the command directly at the prompt. It does not show how to encode ^M and ^Z into a bash script that can be run.

Comment: @user3719188 what about PDU mode? I get "not found" response from the adb shell.

Comment: can send the ^Z  over SSH using printf:
printf '\x1a' > /dev/ttyUSB0

Answer (score 0):

`$ man skill`:

```
SYNOPSIS
        skill [signal] [options] expression

PROCESS SELECTION OPTIONS

   -t, --tty tty
          The next expression is a terminal (tty or pty).

EXAMPLES

        skill -KILL -t /dev/pts/*
            Kill users on PTY devices.
```

So it should be something like(can't verify it) : `skill -STOP --tty /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: I get what you are saying, but thats not what OP meant

Answer (score 0):

For CR (Carriage Return), you can use `\r`. For Ctrl+Z, you can use its key code in the format of `\x<code>` (`<code>` is the ASCII code in hexadecimal); and its code is 26 in decimal, and so `1A` in hex; so Ctrl+Z would be `\x1A`.

So do this:

```bash
echo -e -n 'AT^HCMGS="888"\r' > /dev/ttyUSB0
# Wait for the prompt, do not send the SMS immediately
echo -e -n 'SMS Message\x1A' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Note:** Don't forget to use `-e` option for both `echo`s!